# greedy algorithm for a simple Oympiad problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, greedy, cp

I am a beginner in programming and trying to solve problems from the Australian Informatics Olympiad.

I am stuck on this problem even though to me it seems very simple and straight-forward.
Here's the link to the problem:

[AIO 2020 - Baubles](https://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?problemid=1127&set=aio20)

Below is the snippet of my code that only scored 15%:

```
void solve(){
ll r,b,s,nr,nb;
cin >> r >> b >> s >> nr >> nb;
ll ans = 0;
if (s + r < nr || s + b < nb) ans = 0;
else {
    ll diff_b, diff_r;
    vector<ll>sum;
    
    diff_r = nr - r -1;
    sum.push_back(s - diff_r);
    diff_b = nb - b - 1;
    sum.push_back(s - diff_b);
    sum.push_back(s - diff_b - diff_r - 1);
    ll min = INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sum.size(); i++) if (sum[i] < min) min = sum[i];
    ans = min;
}
cout << ans;}
```

Here I'm looking at reducing `spare` and the initial red/blue if they are greater than the required red/blue, respectively, such that the red/blue + `spare` after reducing will be equal to the required red/blue - 1.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and understand a good way to approach this problem!

Comment: Please include the text of the problem directly in your question, rather than as a weblink. (I cannot even open your link)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more condition in the if statement:

```
if (s + r < nr || s + b < nb || s + r + b < nr + np) ans = 0;
```

This is also affecting your 3rd push (s - diff_b - diff_r - 1) in sum, cause then it might become negative.
Rest seems fine to me.